# Validating JSON response before another function call

Tags: javascript, json

```
var jsonData = Model.CheckData();
```

// If i get the response for then, i must pass the response to the following functions which are below.

```
if (!jsonData) {
    Ti.API.warn("JsonData");
    SendRes(jsonData);
}
```

The problem i am facing is, the functions are getting executed before i get the response at the first place. It should happen sequentially.

**Note**: I cannot call the function `SendRes` on my Json `OnLoad`, as its in a different class all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Model.CheckData()` is an AJAX call. You can give it a callback once ajax is done. You will have to modify that call to accept a callback:

```
//pass a callback to CheckData
Model.CheckData(function(jsonData){
    //do something with jsonData
    if (!jsonData) {
        Ti.API.warn("JsonData");
        SendRes(jsonData);
    }
});

//while in the CheckData function
function CheckData(callback){
    ...ajax call...
    //execute this on receive where "response" is your JSON
    callback(response);
}
```

Comment: @Jospeh: should i place my callback function inside onload like this JsonClientScheduleCareProvider.onload = function () { callback(this.responseText) };